# TikZ code no longer compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
  hobby,
  shapes.geometric,
  decorations,
  decorations.shapes,
  shapes.geometric,
  patterns
}

% http://www.guitex.org/home/it/forum/5-tex-e-latex/83195-la-libreria-hobby-tikz-non-funziona-piu#83203
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_if_exist:NF \prg_stepwise_function:nnnN { \cs_gset_eq:NN \prg_stepwise_function:nnnN \int_step_function:nnnN }
  \cs_if_exist:NF \prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn { \cs_gset_eq:NN \prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn \int_step_inline:nnnn }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{easter bg}{\pgfpoint{5bp}{25bp}}{%
  color(0cm)=(tikz@ball!20);
  color(0.15cm)=(tikz@ball!30);
  color(0.4cm)=(tikz@ball!60);
  color(0.9cm)=(tikz@ball)
}
\tikzoption{easter bg color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{easter bg}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/easter star/.code args={#1 and #2}{
  \pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{easter star}{\pgfpoint{#1}{#2}}{%
  color(0cm)=(tikz@ball!20);
  color(0.3cm)=(tikz@ball!40);
  color(0.65cm)=(tikz@ball!60);
  color(1cm)=(tikz@ball)
  }
 }
 \tikzoption{easter star color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{easter star}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
}
\makeatother

% original code by Paul Gaborit:
% tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72784/arrow-with-two-colors-with-tikz/#72793
\tikzset{
  double path/.style args = {#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
    -, line join = round, line cap = rect,
    shorten >= 0.1cm,
    shorten <= 0.1cm,
    line width = #1,#2, % first path
    postaction = {
      draw,-,
      #3,
      line width = (#1)/1.5,
      shorten <= (#1)/3,
      shorten >= (#1)/3
    } % second path
  }%
}

\tikzset{easter decoration 1/.style = {
    decorate,
    decoration = {
      shape backgrounds,
      shape = star,
      shape size = 7pt,
      shape sep = {0.5cm, between center}
    },
    inner color = yellow,
    outer color = yellow!50!orange,
    draw = red!20!orange
  }%
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{fivepointed stars easter 2}{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{10mm}{10mm}}{\pgfqpoint{10mm}{8mm}}%
{
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{1mm}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpointpolar{18}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{162}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{306}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{90}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{234}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathclose%
  \pgfusepath{fill}
}

\tikzset{easter decoration 3/.style={
    draw=green!17!yellow,
    line width=2pt,
    star
  }
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{fivepointed stars easter 3}{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{12mm}{12mm}}{\pgfqpoint{12mm}{11mm}}%
{
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{1mm}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpointpolar{18}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{162}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{306}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{90}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{234}{1mm}}
  \pgfpathclose%
  \pgfusepath{fill}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
  \node[above,xshift=-3.5cm,yshift=-1.5cm] at (0.5,1){Påskeæg~1};
  % Path clipping.
  \clip[scale=-6](0.5,0.1) to[closed,curve through={ (0.775,0.35) .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35)}] (0.5,0.1);
  % Shading.
  \shade[easter bg color=orange,scale=-6](0.5,0.1) .. (0.775,0.35)[closed=true] .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);
  % Colored paths.
  \draw[double path=5pt colored by orange!80!yellow and yellow,scale=-6] (0.775,0.35) .. (0.735,0.35)  .. (0.65,0.3) .. (0.45,0.4) .. (0.235,0.355) .. (0.225,0.35);
  \draw[double path=5pt colored by orange!80!yellow and yellow,scale=-6] (0.9,0.5) .. (0.775,0.55)  .. (0.55,0.5) .. (0.45,0.6) .. (0.235,0.55) .. (0.1,0.5);
  \draw[double path=5pt colored by orange!80!yellow and yellow,scale=-6] (0.9,0.7) .. (0.775,0.75)  .. (0.55,0.7) .. (0.45,0.8) .. (0.235,0.75) .. (0.1,0.7);
  % Stars.
  \draw[easter decoration 1,scale=-6] (0.775,0.25) .. (0.735,0.25)  .. (0.65,0.2) .. (0.45,0.3) .. (0.235,0.255) .. (0.225,0.25);
  \draw[easter decoration 1,scale=-6] (0.9,0.4) .. (0.775,0.45)  .. (0.55,0.4) .. (0.45,0.5) .. (0.235,0.45) .. (0.1,0.4);
  \draw[easter decoration 1,scale=-6] (0.9,0.6) .. (0.775,0.65)  .. (0.55,0.6) .. (0.45,0.7) .. (0.235,0.65) .. (0.1,0.6);
  \draw[easter decoration 1,scale=-6] (0.9,0.8) .. (0.775,0.85)  .. (0.55,0.8) .. (0.45,0.9) .. (0.235,0.85) .. (0.1,0.8);
  % Draw the border again.
  \draw[scale=-6](0.5,0.1) .. (0.775,0.35)[closed=true] .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
% Easter Egg 2.
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
  \node[above,xshift=-3.5cm,yshift=-1.5cm] at (0.5,1){Påskeæg~2};
  % Path clipping.
  \clip[scale=-6](0.5,0.1) .. (0.775,0.35)[closed=true] .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);
  % Shading.
  \draw[easter bg color=blue!65!cyan,scale=-6,postaction={pattern=fivepointed stars easter 2,pattern color=blue}](0.5,0.1) .. (0.775,0.35)[closed=true] .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);
  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={shift={(-3.5,-3.5)}}]
   \node[star,scale=2.25,easter star=2bp and 10bp, easter star color=cyan!65!blue] at (0.35,0.75){};
   \node[star,scale=1.5,easter star=-2bp and 15bp, easter star color=cyan!85!blue,rotate=10] at (1.45,1.45){};
   \node[star,scale=1.5,easter star=5bp and 10bp, easter star color=cyan!75!blue,rotate=-10] at (-0.5,1.95){};
   \node[star,scale=1.65,easter star=5bp and 15bp, easter star color=cyan!45!blue,rotate=-5] at (-0.75,-0.85){};
   \node[star,scale=1.7,easter star=5bp and 15bp, easter star color=cyan!37!blue,rotate=-3] at (0,-1.65){};
   \node[star,scale=1.5,easter star=5bp and 10bp, easter star color=cyan!60!blue,rotate=2] at (0.85,-0.65){};
   \node[star,scale=1.75,easter star=-2bp and 2bp, easter star color=cyan!60!blue,rotate=14] at (2,0){};     
  \end{scope}
   % Draw the border again.
   \draw[scale=-6](0.5,0.1) .. (0.775,0.35)[closed=true] .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
% Easter Egg 3.
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
  \node[above,xshift=-3.5cm,yshift=-1.5cm] at (0.5,1){Påskeæg~3};
  % Path clipping.
  \clip[scale=-6](0.5,0.1) .. (0.775,0.35)[closed=true] .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);
  % Shading.
  \draw[easter bg color=green!77!blue,scale=-6,postaction={pattern=fivepointed stars easter 3,pattern color=green!20!yellow}](0.5,0.1) .. (0.775,0.35)[closed=true] .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);
  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={shift={(-3.5,-3.5)}}]
   \node[easter decoration 3,scale=2.25] at (0.55,0.65){};
   \node[easter decoration 3,scale=1.5,rotate=10] at (1.45,1.45){};
   \node[easter decoration 3,scale=1.5,rotate=-10] at (-0.5,1.95){};
   \node[easter decoration 3,scale=1.65,rotate=-5] at (-0.75,-0.70){};
   \node[easter decoration 3,scale=1.7,rotate=-3] at (0,-1.65){};
   \node[easter decoration 3,scale=1.5,rotate=2] at (0.85,-0.65){};
   \node[easter decoration 3,scale=1.75,rotate=14] at (2,0){};     
  \end{scope}
  % Draw the border again.
  \draw[scale=-6](0.5,0.1) .. (0.775,0.35)[closed=true] .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Earlier, the code above has produced a picture of three easter eggs, but now I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \fp_if_undefined:NTF 
                                \l_hobby_out_angle_fp {\array_put:Nnx \l_hob...
l.113 ... .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);
```

Can anyone help me modify the code to make it work again?

P.S. I don't use TikZ myself at all.

Comment: You are not loading `hobby`. However changing `\clip[scale=-6](0.5,0.1) .. (0.775,0.35)[closed=true] .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35) .. (0.5,0.1);` to `\clip[scale=-6](0.5,0.1) to[closed,curve through={ (0.775,0.35) .. (0.5,1) .. (0.225,0.35)}] (0.5,0.1);` may be helpful.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks. However, the error persists.

Comment: Could you rerun the code with `\usetikzlibrary{hobby}` in the preamble and report the new error?

Comment: When I try your code with the hobby library loaded then I get an error about decorations, again probably missing some library.  Even though you say you don't use TikZ, you know enough about LaTeX to know that when you cut-and-paste code, you need to get the preamble right!

Comment: @LoopSpace Sorry. I completely missed the code about the libraries. (I've updated my question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package uses LaTeX3 internally very extensively.  So when LaTeX3 functions get updated, the hobby package sometimes needs fixing and updating itself.  Once this has been done, it needs uploading to CTAN.  It appears that although hobby has been updated in line with the latest modifications to LaTeX3, these updates have not yet been uploaded to CTAN and therefore are not in the version that comes with, say, TeXLive.

In the meantime, it is possible to download hobby directly from the [TeX-SX Packages Repository](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files) on Launchpad (download `hobby.dtx`, generate the files with `tex hobby.dtx`).

So try again with the latest version of hobby from TeX-SX Launchpad and I think you'll find that it works just fine.

Comment: Which changes have caused issues?

Comment: When I run `tex hobby.dtx` on the newest [`hobby.dtx`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/hobby.dtx), I now get the error `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.11 var global_
                path = '/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/';`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I just downloaded it from Launchpad to a new directory, ran `tex hobby.dtx` to generate the files (with no errors), took your code and it compiled with no problems.  This is with TeXLive 2014, recently updated.

Comment: @JosephWright This particular problem was caused by the removal of `\fp_if_undefined` from the `fp` segment.  It's used because there are some numbers that the user can configure or can be left unassigned.  So there needs to be a test for "not assigned" and `\fp_if_undefined` seemed the best way to accomplish that.  The workaround is to assign these `fp`s to `\c_inf_fp` at initialisation and test for that instead of undefinedness.  Similar things have happened before.

Comment: @LoopSpace With the newest TeX Live 2014 I still get the error `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   _
l.11 var global_
                path = '/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/';`. Any chance I can make you generate the files and upload them somewhere? :)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg You're not downloading the actual file!  You're downloading the web page containing the file, together with all the javascript and HTML and other junk.  From the link you put in your comment above, click "download file" to get the _actual_ file.